# Java Opensource API to create flow charts

Tags: java, open-source, flowchart

Is there any Java opensource to create flow charts not within the IDE itself, but in a web based application so they can be viewed on a browser? This is like a Cost Control Flowchart, but basically a flow chart.

To avoid any confusion, the business requirement is to allow users to create flow charts and save them to databases. I am not looking to create UMLs of source code or vice versa.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877121/is-there-any-free-online-uml-modelling-tool) points to the right directions but I need to be able to have users draw and then save the drawing/information to the database. Flowchart is the only UML required.

Comment: [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) won't do? Does it need to be opensource?

Comment: I may be able to convince purchasing the license if that works. Have you used it before and if so can you tell me how you used it (in business sense)? Were there any difficulties. BTW, IMO this is very good answer.

Comment: yEd is free, but it's not opensource and only the editor is free; you can buy the backing library though if you need programmatic access

Comment: Good. I am going to contact them and see where they can point me to.

Comment: Check http://diagramo.com It's opensourced and HTML5...who knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it does not need to be "web-based" then [yEd Graph Editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) could be a good choice.

yEd is a free desktop application that can generate high-quality diagrams, either manually, or by importing external data.

Comment: I will accept this answer although I did not end up creating it.